# Python eve: allow_unknown keys with 'datetime' values in embedded schema

Tags: python, eve

I want to have a dictionary with different keys but with datetime value.

I have defined my schema as follows:

```
schema = {
    'entries': {
        'type': 'dict',
        'allow_unknown': True,
        'schema': {
            'entry': {'type': 'datetime', 
            'allow_unknown' : True
           }

        }
    }
}
```

With this, I'm getting different keys in the dict but only `entry` keys will be in datetime format.

I have tried different ways but can't figure out how to get any keys to have datetime values.

Eve v.0.8.1.

I actually tried to validate this with Cerberus and it is valid. But in database it is recognized as string.

```
document = {'entries': {
                        'entry': datetime.now(),
                        'whatever_entry': datetime.now()
                        }
           }
```